# How does the duality functor with respect to $K$ behave on morphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, duality-theorems, yoneda-lemma, representable-functor

In [*A duality formalism in the spirit of Grothendieck and Verdier*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.6020.pdf) Boyarchenko and Drinfeld give the following definition of the terms *dualizing object* and *duality functor*:

> An object $K$ in a monoidal category $M$ is said to be *dualizing* if for every $Y \in M$ the functor $X  \mapsto Hom(X \otimes Y, K)$ is representable by some object $DY \in M$ and the contravariant functor $D : M \rightarrow M$ is an antiequivalence. $D$ is called the *duality functor with respect to $K$*.

After chosing a representing object $DY$ of the functor $Hom(- \otimes Y, K)$ for every object $Y \in Obj(M)$ we obtain an assignment $Y \mapsto DY$ on objects of $M$. However, what morphism $DZ \rightarrow DY$ do we assign to a morphism $f: Y \rightarrow Z$ in $M$? That is, how does $D$ become a functor?

According to page 33 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.10229.pdf), one can use the Yoneda lemma to show that "the assignment $X \mapsto DX$ extends to a functor." I do not see how. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your morphism $f:Y\to Z$ produces (because $\otimes$ is functorial) a morphism $X\otimes f:X\otimes Y\to X\otimes Z$, which in turn induces by composition a function $Hom(X\otimes Z,K)\to Hom(X\otimes Y,K)$. By the definition of $D$, this amounts to a morphism $Hom(X,DZ)\to Hom(X,DY)$.

Furthermore, all of the preceding works for all objects $X$ and the constructions are natural with respect to $X$. That is, we have a natural transformation $Hom(-,DZ)\to Hom(-,DY)$. By Yoneda, this corresponds to a morphism $DZ\to DY$. That morphism is $Df$.

Comment: Thank you! Is it standard practice in category theory to give a functor only on objects and then use representability together with Yoneda to specify what it does on morphisms? That is, to give an argument like this: "Since by representability $Hom(-,DZ) \cong F_Z(-)$ and $Hom(-,DY) \cong F_Y(-)$ and since we have a natural transformation $F_Z(-) \rightarrow F_Y(-)$ (somehow established by $f:Y \rightarrow Z$) we obtain by the Yoneda lemma a morphism $DZ \rightarrow DY$? Do you know any other examples where this is done? Is this assignment on morphisms in some way canonical?

Answer (score 1):

A morphism  $X \rightarrow Y$ induces a natural transformation $Hom(-\otimes Y, Z) \rightarrow Hom(-\otimes X, Z)$ and by the Yoneda Lemma, since $DX$ and $DY$ represent these  functor this natural transformation corresponds to a unique morphism $DY \rightarrow DX$ (the Yoneda embedding is fully faithful). Functoriality follows from the naturality of the Yoneda Lemma.

Comment: Thank you! So it boils down to the following: One shows that the ("precomposition"-)assignment $Hom(X \otimes Z, K) \rightarrow Hom(X \otimes Y, K); g \mapsto g \circ (id_X \otimes f)$ is natural in $X$ (this is essentially due to the functoriality of the tensor product). Then one defines a natural transformation $Hom(-,DZ) \Rightarrow Hom(-,DY)$ as the vertical composition of three natural transformations (using the above precomposition natural transformation as well as natural isomorphisms obtained by the representability of the functor $Hom(-\otimes Y, K)$...

Comment: Using the Yoneda lemma one then obtains a morphism $Df: DZ \rightarrow DY$ from the above natural transformation $Hom(-,DZ) \Rightarrow Hom(-,DY)$. However, I don't see how this assignment is functorial? How does the naturality of the Yoneda lemma help?